# .NET/ADO.NET: Detecting Connection Pool Limits

Tags: .net, system.data

I am getting connection timeouts and I suspect they may be caused by a bug that is allowing me to exceed my connection pool limit. Is there a way to progamatically detect this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this information and a lot of more using [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503%28VS.80%29.aspx) for ADO.Net.

Comment: It will work and there is no other way to see the usage of a thread pools of an application.